# Excel Automatic Calculation at the sheet level only

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that became very slow.
For some reason, wherever I am in the document, if I set Calculation to manual and refresh the current sheet after any change, it is fast enough and serves my purpose.

This is not very comfortable however.

I would like the current sheet (and not the whole document) to be refreshed whenever a cell is changed. This should be done whatever sheet I'm on. How can I do that?

EDIT: let it be clear that I'm not asking for clues on how to make my workbook faster, it was just contextual info. I'm interested in autorefresh only.

Comment: Unless you provide much, much more information, we can only guess! There are too many different factors which might have an impact (automatic links, UDFs, events on sheets or changes, amount of data / sheets / formulas, broken links in named ranges, etc.). So, unless you update your question with all possible factors there is nothing we can do. Yet, if you are updating your question with all possible impact factors then you are also very likely to check them and find the error yourself.

Comment: @Ralph maybe I wasn't clear enough, I've edited my question. I'm working on the slowness of my file but it's not the issue here. A nice quick fix would be to have this autorefresh set, but only at the sheet level, that's what i'm asking here.

Comment: If you want Excel to refresh and calculate everything every time that a cell is changed then you merely need to set `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` which is equivalent to going into the menu: `Formulas` --> `Calculation Options` --> `Automatic`. Yet, that's the default for Excel sheets anyway. Alternatively you can make use of the `Worksheet_Change` event and just drop one line into that sub `ActiveSheet.Calculate`.

Comment: I don't want everything to be refreshed, that's too slow, I want only the current sheet to be refreshed, without clicking each time on "Calculate Sheet"

Comment: I'll try your second suggestion, thanks. However that requires me to drop that line in every worksheet object right?

Comment: For some reason Activesheet.calculate returns an error, as ThisWorksheet.calculate, but me.calculate, as in @teylin 's answer, works just fine

Comment: If your sheet would properly update without allowing updates of the other data, then it seems this sheet is independent of the others. Consider making this sheet its own workbook.

Comment: Unfortunately all sheets are connected, but given the types of links I have I'm happy to refresh only the active sheet, and just update all when I save

Answer (score 1):

Charles Williams has extensive information, techniques and code on calculation on his website http://decisionmodels.com. Quoting from [this page](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsh.htm):

> Another method uses the worksheet.enablecalculation property. When
>   this property is changed all the formulae on the worksheet are flagged
>   as uncalculated, so toggling the property to false and then back to
>   true for all sheets in all open workbooks will cause the next
>   calculation to be a full calculation.

```
> Dim oSht as worksheet Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual
> 
> for each oSht in Worksheets oSht.enablecalculation=false
> osht.enablecalculation=true next osht
> 
> Application.calculate
```

> You can also use this method for a single worksheet to do a full sheet
>   calculate.

You can easily work this technique into the Worsheet_Change event, like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Me.EnableCalculation = False
Me.EnableCalculation = True
Me.Calculate

End Sub
```

This will do a full calculation of the current sheet only and leave all other sheets uncalculated.

Comment: Thanks @teylin, I could make it work thanks to your answer, but I reduced it to 
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual Then Me.Calculate
End Sub
I'm not sure what is the purpose of Me.EnableCalculation = False / Me.EnableCalculation = True here, can you elaborate ?

Comment: You say that "toggling the property to false and then back to true for all sheets in all open workbooks will cause the next calculation to be a full calculation." but as far as i understand, application.calculate is already a full calculation, and in a similar way, in the second part, me.calculate seems sufficient to me

Comment: It's a quote from the page where calculation is discussed in the context of the workbook. Just have a read. It has very useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Calculation event can happen at the Application, Worksheet or Range level (but not the Workbook level.)

If you have calculation mode set to manual but want the current worksheet (only) updated when you enter something, you could add a worksheet change event (putting the code in the relevant sheet.)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal ChangedRng As Range)
    ChangedRng.Worksheet.Calculate
End Sub
```

This will recalculate just the worksheet and not the rest of the Workbook or any other workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

*As the provided answers don't fully satisfy me here is my own, borrowing from their appreciated help. It's possible that I've missed some nuance from teylyn's answer. I'll gladly edit if it's relevant.*

There doesn't seem to be a way to handle change events at the APPLICATION level.

So all changes must be handled at the SHEET level.

This can be done by copying and pasting this bit of code in EVERY Sheet object of the workbook (and remember to copy and paste it it whenever you add a new sheet):

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Me.Calculate
End Sub
```

However because of the tedious copy pastes we had to do, we may want to turn this feature off easily without going back to each sheet object.

We may also want to avoid entering a loop of hell if we do mass change on one sheet (say through a macro, a drag & drop, or a ctrl+H).

To do this we add a new sheet called WS_refresh where we set 3 values :

- in A2: Yes/No to enable/disable our new feature
- in A4: time of latest refresh
- in A6: min interval to allow refresh, in sec (I've set it to 1)

Now when we change values in several cells in a short amount on time, autorefresh will only work on the first change, avoiding previously mentioned loops of hell. If you like to live dangerously set A6 to 0.

This is what should be copied and pasted in every sheet object:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
auto_refresh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS_refresh").Range("A2")
If auto_refresh = "Yes" Then
    last_refresh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS_refresh").Range("A4")
    refresh_interval_sec = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS_refresh").Range("A6")
    refresh_interval_tv = TimeValue("0:00:" & refresh_interval_sec)
    If Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual And Now() > last_refresh + refresh_interval_tv Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS_refresh").Range("A4") = Now()
        Me.Calculate
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I know this is a really old answer. But, I'm looking at it, so I thought I'd comment. You can handle sheet change events at the workbook level. It's the SheetChange event (Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)). Anyway, no need to copy paste that to every worksheet module.

Comment: Thanks Chip, don't hesitate to post as an answer, this question gets a lot of views so it doesn't matter if it's old. As for me I'm have been able to stay far from VBA for a while and I'm not in any rush to jump back in tbh :).